# How can I limit each team to have 5 players each and have 2 spectators in my CSGO server?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, counter-strike

I currently have a CS:GO server that holds up to 12 players but I don't want to have it so its a 6v6. I would like so the teams are limited to 5 players each and there can be 2 spectators watching until a slot opens up.

If anyone knows a way to do this (preferablly with the.cfg's I would greatly appreciate it. I am running the configs mainly with the server.cfg and gamemode_competitive.cfg

Answer (score 3):

Take your config and edit the following lines to your needs:

```
`mp_spectators_max "2" // How many spectators are allowed in a match.`

`maxplayers "10"`
```

and you could try this as bonus to make it "competitive"

```
sv_competitive_official_5v5 "0" // Enable to force the server to show 5v5 scoreboards and allows spectators to see characters through walls.
```

If you need anything else, [**here is a link**](http://www.gamerconfig.eu/commands/counter-strike-global-offensive/) with 2483 console commands (not sure if that are all available commands but definitely all you'll ever need)

**Update:**

So that the commands dont work I just found that there is a -maxplayers_override command but i dont know if this still works. However there is [**an entry on the Valve Dev Page**](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive_Dedicated_Servers_Known_Issues#Maxplayers_doesn.27t_work.2Fis_overridden) about this problem which you could try. I just found another comment in [**the steam forum**](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2724702) which seems to be important.

> The maxplayers command must be above the convars segment. Put that maxplayer into the gamemode part you are trying to change.

You have to write the following in the gamemodes/gamemodes_server.txt

```
 "GameModes_Server.txt"
 {
   "gameTypes"
   {
     "classic"
     {
       "gameModes"
       {
         "competitive"
         {
           maxplayers      "6"
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: I have looked over the page that you have linked me that shows me the Valve Dev Page but using the techniques that they describe there still allows 6 players each team. Is there any alternative link or in someway you can further assist me to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try to use put the maxplayer command above the convars segment?